# Disable wifi signin popup?

Tags: 8.0-oreo

When I connect to a hotspot that requires signin, I don't want a popup that fills the entire screen. A simple notification would suffice.

Can this popup be disabled on Android 8?

Samsung Galaxy S9+

Comment: Please also give more information on your Android Smartphone, different models may have different options and layout. First, Check your Advanced Wi-Fi Settings if there's an option to disable the popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: it's not possible because this popup come from the SystemUI or from the Framework apk.
It's not come from a file that contain a setting, it's a JAVA runtime code.

Some customs ROMs could integrate it (not sure), but it's not the case of Android stock.